# SceneKit camera causes objects to Not Show Up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3d, scenekit

I want to be able to create a custom camera node in SceneKit and view my scene from it (instead of the default camera).

However, I've been encountering a very strange issue with SceneKit:

- If I use `SCNCamera`, nothing shows up in my scene.
- If I don't use `SCNCamera`, the objects in my scene render
  correctly.

This is the code I am using (very simple code; from a tutorial):

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sceneView = SCNView()
        sceneView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)

        let scene = SCNScene()

        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        // If the below line of code is commented out (so no SCNCamera is added), everything shows up
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 5)
        sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        cameraNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        sceneView.scene = scene

    }
}
```

This seems pretty straightforward, yet I can't find any reason why this is happening on SO, etc.

Strangely, I also observe that if I try to access the camera node via `sceneView.pointOfView`, I get **`nil`**, even though `sceneView.allowsCameraControl` is set to **`true`**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's a recent post on the Apple dev forums that may be related: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/129049

Answer (score 1):

The sphere is a child node of the camera, without any offset (its `position` is `(0, 0, 0)`) and so the camera is *inside* the sphere. And if the sphere's material isn't `doubleSided` then you won't see anything.

Comment: Ah yes, I can at least see the sphere now. Thank you. But I'm still wondering why pointOfView is nil in this example? Shouldn't SceneKit automatically create a camera node for you?

Comment: It does but it's not user accessible.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you mean is that the default cameraNode is not accessible by default. In my case however, I have set allowsCameraControl = true, which according to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768031/can-i-get-the-scnview-camera-position-when-using-allowscameracontrol/30278102 will create a default camera node accessible through the .pointOfView property. Yet, when I try to access it, the property returns nil. Could you please elaborate on exactly what you mean by it's not user accessible?